# "no matching function for call" when trying to use the erase function on a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, erase

I'm trying to use the erase function to delete any ints from my vector with a value of 0.

```
void eliminateZeroes(std::vector<int> &answers){
    auto i = answers.cbegin();
    while(i != answers.cend()){
        if(*i == 0){
            i = answers.erase(i);
        }else{
            i++;
        }

    }
```

I expect the function to remove any items from the vector which are valued 0.

Error message:

```
/home/ec2-user/environment/DP378-Havel_Hakimi_-_Easy/main.cpp: In function ‘void eliminateZeroes(std::vector<int>&)’:
/home/ec2-user/environment/DP378-Havel_Hakimi_-_Easy/main.cpp:32:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<int>::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >&)’
                 i = answers.erase(i);
                                    ^
/home/ec2-user/environment/DP378-Havel_Hakimi_-_Easy/main.cpp:32:36: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.5/vector:69:0,
                 from /home/ec2-user/environment/DP378-Havel_Hakimi_-_Easy/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/bits/vector.tcc:134:5: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = int*]
     vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/bits/vector.tcc:134:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >’ to ‘std::vector<int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >}’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/bits/vector.tcc:146:5: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = int*]
     vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/bits/vector.tcc:146:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

Comment: I remember a point where libstdc++ had started supporting C++11 but some containers were missing the new `erase(const_iterator)` overloads. But I don't think `std::vector` had that issue.

Comment: @TomJB It seems you are using an old compiler. Write  auto i = answers.begin(); instead of auto i = answers.cbegin();

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That was it!! Thank you so much. As an added bonus my function worked first time it compiled...nice for a change!

Comment: BTW, @TomJB: instead of writing your own loop, look at the `std::remove` algorithm and the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) of C++.  That's much more efficient, as the elements then only need to be moved at most once each.

Comment: @TomJB See also my answer.

Comment: @TobySpeight - thanks to you both. All very helpful information for a beginner programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using an old compiler that does not completely support the C++ 11 Standard.

The problem is that the constant iterator produced by the function `cbegin`

```
auto i = answers.cbegin();
```

can not be converted to a non-constant iterator that is used in the old declaration of the member function `erase` prior the C++ 11 Standard.

In the current C++ Standard the function is declared like

```
iterator erase(const_iterator position);
```

and your code should compile.

So instead of

```
auto i = answers.cbegin();
```

you need to use

```
auto i = answers.begin();
```

But in any case it is better to define the function the following way

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> & eliminateZeroes( std::vector<int> &answers )
{
    answers.erase( std::remove( answers.begin(), answers.end(), 0 ), answers.end() );

    return answers;
}
```

If your compiler supports general functions `begin`, `end` and so on declared in the header `<iterator>` then the function can be rewritten also like

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::vector<int> & eliminateZeroes( std::vector<int> &answers )
{
    answers.erase( std::remove( std::begin( answers ), std::end( answers ), 0 ), std::end( answers ) );

    return answers;
}
```

Comment: No need for to qualify `std::begin` and `std::end`, they will be found by ADL.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am considering such an approach as a bad style of programming.:)

Comment: Then `using std::begin;` in the local scope so a future reader understands it will be found.  But disabling ADL is worse then relying on it.

Comment: Can I ask a question about this? The std::remove function apparently returns: 'An iterator to the element that follows the last element not removed.'. It is returning this to the erase function, which erases the item at the location pointed to by the iterator. To me this seems like the erase function is being told to delete something that we don't want it to? It works beautifully so I must be misunderstanding.

Comment: @TomJB The erase function used in the demonstrative program uses two iterators. The first one points to the first element that was removed by std::remove and the second iterator points to the end of the sequence. That is the tail of the sequence contains elements that we are going to erase.

Comment: Ah that makes sense now. Thank you.